# JPA Transactional method updates the column after already saving it

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, persistence

Im saving an Object that is POSTed in REST Webservice , but Im trying to update some fields just before that. I have an A class that has a B as its property (no relationship, just a field - complexity due to  this field being a separate JSON field/object). I am trying to update B's property before A is persisted which actually works just fine.. EXCEPT after it inserts the new class , it also updates the field. Something like that:

```
public class A {
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
Long id;

@Lob
@Convert(converter = BConverter.class)
B b_field;
}

public class B {
List<String> someVals;
List<Map<String, String>> amts;
}






@Converter
public class BConverter implements AttributeConverter<B, String> {
    
    private final static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(B b) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(b);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {....
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public B convertToEntityAttribute(String bVal) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(bVal, B.class);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ......
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the POST method for persisting:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public A saveA(A a){
  List<Map<String, String>> amts= new ArrayList<>();
  amts.add(....here goes some hashmap...);
  a.getB_field.setAmts(amts);
  return repository.save(a);
}
```

Fired queries are:

```
insert into A (id, b_field) -> here b_field already contains the added values from above
update A set b_field =? where id=?  -> same object that is already inserted. Basically useless
```

I can imagine it has to do with Transaction being committed, but dont understand why it doesnt get that there isnt any change. Any ideas? Thank you!!

Comment: Is the `id` field annotated with `@Id`? Is it different if it is?

Comment: yes, it is for class A. Ill update the annotations in the questions

Comment: Have you tried annotating `id` of `B` with `@Id`?

Comment: The ID of B is not an ID, it is just a random field. I can change that in the example as well. B is more of a structure - like I said it was convinient with JSON column

Comment: This smells like A is triggered to be inserted somewhere else before saveA() is invoked. That would be the simplest logical explanation to this result. And since I don't believe in black magic and neither should you, I would suggest you investigate the code to see if what I say may be true.

Comment: When I debug, it looks more like insert is triggered by save() and the update is coming up during the commit . I can post the concrete method name later

Comment: What kind of database are you using Nikki? What datatype are you using for actually storing the ```b_field```? A ```BLOB```? What is the actual output of ```BConverter```? A ```byte[]```?

Comment: Can you share your repository implementation? Can you add a print/log statement in this method to confirm how many times it is being called per request? You may add the @DynamicUpdate annotation above class `A`. This will encourage hibernate to check for newly changed attribute values instead of using cached sql statements to run queries. Let us know the changes if any.

Comment: @jccampanero It is Mysql and JSON column. Ive added the converter

Comment: @ggordon I also have DynamicUpdate on A - that doesnt make a difference. I dont have a custom method in repository here - I am using the standard save() from CrudRepository

Comment: And, do you try to ```persist``` instead of ```save``` the class ```A```? Do you obtain the same results?

Comment: @jccampanero tried that - is the same and the method is only being called once. I think I will be moving away towards NativeQueries - this is not working whatever I do :(

Comment: Have you tried the ```hibernate-types``` [project](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types/) from Vlad Mihalcea? See: https://vladmihalcea.com/java-map-json-jpa-hibernate/, maybe it can be of any help.

Comment: Either way, the problem could be related to several things. For instance, maybe the need of initialization of the entity ```id``` field. Another possibility is that, even after insertion of the entity `` `A```, for any reason, Hibernate consider the instance dirty and generate an update as a consequence.

Comment: @jccampanero thank you for the link - I got an idea to change the map to JsonNode and that works!

Comment: Nice Nikki!! I'm glad I was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I came closest to an answer myself, at least for now:
it is the Map that breaks the flow. There are specialties when it comes to Maps and JPA, but still none of them worked for me till now in this case.
Workaround: If I create a class with defined fields instead of dynamic map it works great. 
**UPDATE:**
Inspired by a link from @jccampanero, Ive changed Map to JsonNode and am building a node dynamically with JsonNodeFactory. That works like a charm!